# FTP download problems with iptables -- Port 21 connection is allowed but "Network is unreachable"

Tags: linux, iptables, ftp

I'm trying to connect to an FTP site but with, e.g., `wget`:

```
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /gcrypt/gnutls ... done.
==> SIZE v3.2 ... done.
==> PASV ... couldn't connect to 217.69.76.55 port 40258: Network is unreachable
```

If I disable iptables, it works, so obviously that is the problem.  Yet I'm sure I have everything set up properly:

```
# Accept related, established...
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# ftp/http(s) clients
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21,80,443,8080 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iptables needs some kernel modules loaded in order for "RELATED, ESTABLISHED" to work.  If your HTTP clients are okay, you obviously have some of them.

```
 > lsmod | grep conntrack
 nf_conntrack_ipv4      20258  6 
 nf_defrag_ipv4         12702  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
 xt_conntrack           12760  6 
 nf_conntrack           99996  2 xt_conntrack,nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

However, the one for ftp, `nf_conntrack_ftp`, is additional and, unlike a device or filesystem driver, will not be loaded automatically by the kernel.

```
 > modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp
```

Should do it.  There is not AFAIK a cross-distro method for autoloading modules at boot, but on Fedora you can add:

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp"
```

to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config`.  On other systems which use `systemd` but do not have this file, see `man modules-load.d`.